# Customized switch toggle button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

I wan't to customized my switch in android. The problem is that the default button overlay my own drawable.

What have i done:

1. create my own graphics (2 graphics)
2. create a xml in the drawable folder, that's look like this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_female" android:state_checked="false"/>
>     <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_male" android:state_checked="true"/>
> </selector>
> ```

3. and my switch definition looks like this:

> ```
> <Switch
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text=""
>             android:textOff=""
>             android:textOn=""
>             android:id="@+id/genderSwitchOne"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewPersonGender"
>             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/gender_switch"/>
> ```

but what i get is this:

[image: myswitchbutton]

it's possible to remove the default button (over the "em" from female)?

Thanks in advance.

PS: sorry but i can not paste the android xml without blockquote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:thumb="@null"` on the `Switch` XML element. This will erase the thumb drawable from display.

EDIT: As the above produced an NPE, `android:thumb="@android:color/transparent"` should do the trick as this will get loaded as an actual `ColorDrawable`.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to make custom colored two state thumb, keep original background and implement `textOn` and `textOff` Instead of hardcoding text into the background image. I've not tested this though.

Comment: with your suggestion i get a `java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.Switch.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(Switch.java:822)`